# Python to Java translation of short code

Tags: java, python

I found this really simple code written in Python:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
data=opener.open(request)
data.read(1024)
length=ord(data.read(1))*8
print data.read(length)
```

and I want to rewrite it in Java. Can you help me? I can't seem to find what the data.read() methods are for, Python docs really confuse me. Newbie here.

Comment: edit: yes, sorry, it was wrong.

Comment: looks like a homework assignment... otherwise it's strange that you "found" this code, don't know what it does, but need it in Java.

Comment: yes it's a homework. you got me. where do I sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It opens a URL for reading, reads 1 kibibyte of data and discards it, reads one byte of data, turns that byte into a number, multiplies it by 8, and reads that many more bytes.

Comment: when you say it discards it, does the reading afterwards continue from that point? 1024? maybe that's why it's there..